# Python TCP Socket multiple file transfer - all data ends up in the first file

Tags: python, sockets, networking, file-transfer

I'm trying to write an app that can transfer multiple files, but on receiver ends all the data ends up on the first file and the other ones have 0B.

I have defined 4 functions. Two of which send and receive details about files (name, size and the total number of files to be transmitted) and two that send and receive the files.
The details about files and size are send and received correctly, but the receiver put all data from all the files in the first file transmitted (it`s size appear to be sum of all files' sizes) and the rest of them appear to have 0B.

sender's code:

```
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
def send_data(conn, file_name, file_size, numbers_files):

       
      for i in range(numbers_files):
        
        bar = tqdm.tqdm(range(file_size[i]), f"Sending {file_name[i]}, to {ADDR}", unit="B", unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=BUFFER_SIZE)  # progress bar

        with open(file_name[i], "rb") as f:  # open file in read and byte modes
            while True:
                data = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)  # read 4096 bytes at once

                if not data:  # if there is no more data, exit
                     break

                conn.sendall(data)  # send data
                msg = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()  # receive confirmation

                bar.update(len(data))  # update progress bar

        f.close()  # close file
```

receiver's code:

```
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
def receive_data(conn, file_info):

    file_name = file_info[0]
    file_size = file_info[1]
    numbers_files = file_info[2]

    for i in range(numbers_files):
        bar = tqdm.tqdm(range(file_size[i]), f"Receiving {file_name[i]}", unit="B", unit_scale=True,
                        unit_divisor=BUFFER_SIZE)

        with open(file_name[i], "wb") as f:  # open file in write and byte modes
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)  # receives data

                if not data:
                    f.close()
                    break

                f.write(data)  # write data in elements
                conn.send("Data received".encode())  # send confirmation
                bar.update(len(data))  # update the progress bar
    conn.close
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The receive function reads everything from the socket, and since you're sending all of the data at once, the socket contains ALL of the files. `if not data` never gets True until it reaches the end of the final file

Comment: You don't need `f.close()` when you use `with`. That automatically closes the file.

Comment: Note that what you're sending through the socket is data, not files. The receiving side doesn't know when one file starts and another ends